# Entity Framework not saving changes to a Local DB

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

I'm new to C# and Entity Framework and I'm trying to write an application to improve my knowledge.

I think I've set up everything correctly and I don't get any type of error. The problem is that I can not add a new record to localDb in Visual Studio 2017.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
private void Save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var context = new Database1Entities();

        var aMemberdef = new Members()
        {
            FirstName = Name_txt.Text,
            LastName = LastName_txt.Text
        };

        context.Members.Add(aMemberdef);
        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

and here my `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                 requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Database1Entities" 
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/EF.Model1.csdl|res://*/EF.Model1.ssdl|res://*/EF.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Data\Database1.mdf; initial catalog=Database1; integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory  
             type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I think there is some mistake in the app config file but the connection string was generated by entity framework. So I'm stuck [MyDB Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1PDk.png)

Comment: What do you mean you 'cannot add a new record'... do you get an error? Did you debug the code and ensure that it has actually been run?

Comment: You probably overwrite your database with each run.

Comment: With such a problem, don't go all the way with GUI, buttons and interaction. Just write a small console application, instantiate the dbcontext in main, query for existing data, add data to test, query again. You need to know whether the data are instantly lost or at application restart as GertArnold suggested.

Comment: Try creating  a row manually in the table and then run your code to see if the db get overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Because your localdb is copied to bin folder every time you run it. It gets overwritten everytime you run/debug it. Main file in the project folder is not updated.
For detailed answer:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/393bddc6-0b85-4c27-9475-27172e50d2d9/entity-framework-doesnt-save-new-record-into-database?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: And it is also why you don't get any errors while running the program